# How to handle questions which you find on-topic but once answered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

I think I have found [a good example of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492609/declaration-declaring-recordset-always-creates-syntax-error-in-vba) which both make me want to answer because I find the question itself on-topic but also vote to close once answered.

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers...

If I am not completely misunderstanding the first part of this off-topic reason this question was caused by a simple typo, it should be solved now but the part about helping future visitors could be questionable here.

The original title of the question:

*`Declaration : declaring Recordset always creates syntax error in VBA`*

in very unlikely to be the exact phrase someone (*a potential future visitor*) will type in a search engine.

After editing the title to

*`Variable declaration syntax error`*

now the question may have just become easily reachable to anyone who *has a problem with a variable declaration*...

Here are my questions regarding the above:

- how do I handle this situation? Do I vote to close or leave it open?
- is it due to me abusing the close reason? When, in what cases should I be using this close reason?

Update (*do not consider too-broad as this is just another example of a question to discuss*)

[could not load file or assembly microsoft.office.interop.excel version 15.0.0.0 in windows xp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572166/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-office-interop-excel-version-15-0-0-0)

Comment: Technically I wouldn't call that a typo. The OP clearly didn't know that using a '.' in a VisualBasic variable name isn't allowed. I'm probably just splitting hairs though.

Comment: Well, what would a typo be then? `rst` used in place of `rs`? ;/ that's exactly why I am confused about when to use this close reason.

Comment: To me, a typo would something like using string instead of String in Java.

Comment: I think best would be creating one canonical (naming rule) Q&A for the language and then closing all of them, preferably without answering though I won't hold my breath, as duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a certain class of "typo" questions that may be worth answering. However, for the most part, many of these questions are simply due to a blatant lack of effort on the part of the asker (in debugging, research, and consulting documentation). These are the types of low quality questions that are so often the subject of complaint here.

I believe the best thing to do is to close, and not answer *at all*, not even in comments, as this only gives positive reinforcement to this type of question. I view the close system as a way to let an OP know what is and is not acceptable here. If the question is closed but answered anyways, then the only thing the OP learns is they can always come here to get the quick answer they're looking for, without putting any effort in - because, who cares if it's closed if it's answered?

If anything, I would leave a comment that *does not state the answer itself*, but rather suggests ways to debug the problem. For example, the asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868627/syntax-error-in-from-clause-access-sql) would benefit far more from something along the lines of "A good approach to debugging query syntax errors is to print out the query and make sure it is what you think it is" in a comment.

Comment: ++ thanks. Now I know! Now I agree!

Answer (score 0):

Whether to close questions where the answer is merely to point out a typo is another question altogether - but it helps the original asker but no-one else, probably closing is the best approach.

**EDIT inspired by comments:** Sometimes we cannot be sure if a question contains a typo, or if the incorrect characters are down to lack of understanding of the technology about which they are asking; incorrect or misplaced punctuation and capitalisation are likely sources of mistakes to someone with expertise in one language learning a new language where the rules are subtly different.

If in doubt, I would suggest leaving the question open.

I think the original title the the question was actually better - it is more specific, and specific titles are encouraged in [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Furthermore, Google results aren't limited to exact phrases, but anyone with a genuine difficulty with the topic is less likely to see this particular question as originally titled, but that's OK as they probably would not learn anything from it anyway.